# Parâmetros para chamada externa

Tags: c, c++, linux, funções, parâmetros

Utilizo Linux e por padrão (ou pelo menos no meu caso) ele não tem controle de brilho da tela, porém tem um programa que da pra controlar.

A questão aqui é que eu quero pegar o valor do "usuário" e usar esse valor em uma função tipo: `system("sudo light - Valor que receber aqui");`, da pra pegar o valor e usar na função com C++?

O que eu fiz até agora (estou implementando itens que utilizo diariamente): [ideone.com/QFHA6c](http://ideone.com/QFHA6c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considero isso uma gambiarra. Não que não possa ser feito, mas prefira fazer em código mesmo. Tem uma [pergunta sobre isso no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5811279/221800) que pode ajudar. Tem [mais uma relacionada lá](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1963473/221800).

Se quiser insistir:

```
printf("system returnou %d", WEXITSTATUS(system("sudo light")));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/IO/ReturnCode.c).

Comment: Vlw, tentei implementar, mas deu vários erros ( biblioteca / funções ) ... estou fazendo uma gambiara maior ainda : imgur.com/a/4cxbM

Answer (score 2):

**Dá sim**; basta chamar a função e guardar a mensagem de retorno. Depois disso, em uma nova variável, edite a *string* que vai em `system();` (neste caso, irá tratá-la como uma variável do tipo String ou uma simples string em C mesmo) e pronto. Basta jogar dentro de `system();`!

Quando digo editar a string.. Penso bastante em C e as funções de `string.h`. Em C++ fica mais fácil, já que existe o tipo String.

Comment: Vlw, teria mais informações sobre o processo pra me indicar ?